# Image files do not show up on mounted SD card but are still visible via the camera

Tags: linux, mount, sd-card, manjaro

I am using Manjaro Linux on my Chromebook Pixel. My camera is Oly E-M5. I mount the SD card with the command

```
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdc1 /media/sdcard
```

The card seems to mount correctly, and I can see the directory where the images should be stored (`/DCIM/100OLYMP/`), as well as two other files I placed on the root of the SD card. However, the `100OLYMP` folder is empty. The “free space” indicator in [Thunar](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/start) tells me it is also almost empty.

However, I can browse all the images I have taken when the SD card is in the camera. I haven't tried any other computers yet as none of my friends have SD card readers. Any ideas? 
Here is the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
/dev/sdc1  *    32768 124735487 124702720 59.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: By the way, there are inexpensive SD card adapters that will let you plug an SD card into an ordinary USB port as if it were an ordinary thumb drive.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mount the SD card via `exfat`:

```
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdc1 /media/sdcard
```

But to my knowledge, most camera SD cards are DOS formatted. So you would use a command like this to view contents:

```
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/sdc1 /media/sdcard
```

I believe the reason you can mount the SD card with `exfat` but can’t view the contents is that `exfat` assumes FAT32 for the disk, but `msdos` is FAT16.

Comment: Note the output of fdisk. The card is indeed exfat formatted, as I prefer how that format handles large files (e.g. allowing them to exist)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a 64GB card, which is necessarily SDXC. I cannot find the specification of the card reader on the Chromebook, but I suspect it may be only SDHC, with a size limit of 32GB. I can't be completely sure, because I have never plugged an SDXC card into an SDHC reader, so I don't know if you can see any of its file system when you do.

You have two options for reading the card on your Chromebook:-

- Buy a USB card reader with SDXC support.
- Connect the camera with an appropriate USB cable, and it will appear as an external disc.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a likely cause... However I get the same results when plugging the camera in with the included cable.

Comment: That is very puzzling. I don't know what else to suggest. Have you got access to a Windows system to try it on that? Not that I have any fondness for Windows, but most camera manufacturers supply Windows software to the exclusion of other OS, so one can assume that most testing has been done with that.

Comment: Plugging the camera USB cable in gives me 3 options on the camera - MTP, storage, and charge. I haven't been able to get MTP-connect working yet and am generally not a fan of MTP; the storage option seems to work as if the camera is an SD card reader.
Interestingly, if I 'mount /dev/sdc1 /media/sdcard' without specifying filesystem type, I get an error when using the built in SD card reader. But it mounts correctly when using the camera + usb cable.
Also, I was able to successfully copy all data from the SD card with my friend's windows computer and the USB cable + camera. No drivers necessary

Comment: I don't know Manjaro Linux, but I have generally found Ubuntu is a lot less discriminating than Windows when mounting external discs, which it does automatically. I share your misgivings over MTP, but I am unclear as to exactly what happens when you plug in the camera: you say it mounts correctly, but can you read the files or not?

Comment: When you connected the camera to your friends windows box were the files copied via MTP? (Likely so)